How do I do calculations with a sliding window while being memory-efficient?
I am working with very large (several GB) 2-dimensional square NumPy arrays. Given an input array a, for each element, I would like to find the direction of its largest adjacent neighbor. I am using the provided sliding window view to try to avoid creating unnecessary copies:
# a is an L x L array of type np.float32
swv = sliding_window_view(a, (3, 3)) # (L-2) x (L-2) x 3 x 3
directions = swv.reshape(L-2, L-2, 9)[:,:,1::2].argmax(axis = 2).astype(np.uint8)

However, calling reshape here creates a (L-2) x (L-2) x 9 copy instead of a view, which consumes an undesirably large chunk of memory. Is there a way to do this operation in a vectorized fashion, but with a smaller memory footprint?
EDIT: Many of the responses are geared towards NumPy, which uses CPU (since that's what I initially asked, to simplify the problem). Would the optimal strategy be different for using CuPy, which is NumPy for GPU? As far as I know, it makes using Numba much less straightforward.

Can you do the 1::2 slice on the (3,3)? Reshape of a sliding window is bad, slicing directly keeps the view.  Agregation like max, avg etc is also ok.

Maybe the best option is to throw away sliding_window_view and implement it with numba.

@ken It would be more efficient because of the better use of the CPU cache and registers. However, the code is gonna be much bigger because of the bound checking (4 conditions) combined with argmax (requiring the index of the value, not just the max) of the 5 items. For sake of performance, we can write a loop for the center values avoiding useless conditions, but it makes the code even bigger and more complex though it is also more efficient. The benefit of a Numba implementation is also that the memory overhead is tiny (i.e. O(1) which is optimal).

@JérômeRichard I'm not sure I'm following... Since sliding_window_view doesn't handle the edges, I don't think the bound check is necessary. So argmax is the only hard piece. However, IMHO, the logical complexity would be simpler if you consider that the current implementation slices the sliding window just to get the four neighbors.

I'm also wondering if stencil could be used for this (I haven't tested it). If that's the case, argmax will literally be the only piece.

@ken Oh right, indeed, there is no need for bound checks since the output is of size L-2. I missed that. However, there is still 3 conditions for the 4 neighbours with some boring index handling to do, the direction maximizing the value should be stored in each condition as well as the maximum found so far. Thus, about 10 lines in 2 nested loops. I also tend to personally prefer loops though it is not so great here. This is indeed a kind of unusual stencil (so unusual that I do not expect Python modules to provide a way to express it easily).

Since using sliding_window_view is not efficient for your use case, I will provide an alternative using Numba.
First, to simplify the implementation, define the following argmax alternative.
from numba import njit


@njit
def argmax(*values):
    """argmax alternative that can take an arbitrary number of arguments.

    Usage: argmax(0, 1, 3, 2)  # 2
    """
    max_arg = 0
    max_value = values[0]
    for i in range(1, len(values)):
        value = values[i]
        if value > max_value:
            max_value = value
            max_arg = i
    return max_arg

This is a standard argmax function, except it takes multiple scalar arguments instead of a single numpy array.
Using this argmax alternative, your operation can be easily re-implemented.
@njit(cache=True)
def neighbor_argmax(a):
    height, width = a.shape[0] - 2, a.shape[1] - 2
    out = np.empty((height, width), dtype=np.uint8)
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            # window: a[y:y + 3, x:x + 3]
            # center: a[y + 1, x + 1]
            out[y, x] = argmax(
                a[y, x + 1],  # up
                a[y + 1, x],  # left
                a[y + 1, x + 2],  # right
                a[y + 2, x + 1],  # down
            )
    return out

This function requires only a few variables to operate, excluding the input and output buffers.
So we don't need to worry about memory footprint.
Alternatively, you can use stencil, a sliding window utility for Numba.
With stencil, you only need to define the kernel. Numba will take care of the rest.
from numba import njit, stencil

@stencil
def kernel(window):
    # window: window[-1:2, -1:2]
    # center: window[0, 0]
    return np.uint8(  # Don't forget to cast to np.uint8.
        argmax(
            window[-1, 0],  # up
            window[0, -1],  # left
            window[0, 1],  # right
            window[1, 0],  # down
        )
    )


@njit(cache=True)
def neighbor_argmax_stencil(a):
    return kernel(a)[1:-1, 1:-1]  # Slicing is not mandatory.

It can also be inlined, if you like.
@njit(cache=True)
def neighbor_argmax_stencil_inlined(a):
    f = stencil(lambda w: np.uint8(argmax(w[-1, 0], w[0, -1], w[0, 1], w[1, 0])))
    return f(a)[1:-1, 1:-1]  # Slicing is not mandatory.

However, stencil is very limited in functionality and cannot completely replace sliding_window_view.
One difference is that there is no option to skip the edges.
It is always padded with a constant value (0 by default).
That is, if you put (L, L) matrix, you will get (L, L) output, not (L-2, L-2).
This is why I am slicing the output in the code above to match your implementation.
However, this may not be the desired behavior, as it breaks memory contiguity.
You can copy after slicing, but be aware that it will increase the peak memory usage.
In addition, it should be noted that these functions can also be easily adapted for multi-threading.
For details, please refer to the benchmark code below.
Here is the benchmark.
import math
import timeit

import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange, stencil
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view


def baseline(a):
    L = a.shape[0]
    swv = sliding_window_view(a, (3, 3))  # (L-2) x (L-2) x 3 x 3
    directions = swv.reshape(L - 2, L - 2, 9)[:, :, 1::2].argmax(axis=2).astype(np.uint8)
    return directions


@njit
def argmax(*values):
    """argmax alternative that can accept an arbitrary number of arguments.

    Usage: argmax(0, 1, 3, 2)  # 2
    """
    max_arg = 0
    max_value = values[0]
    for i in range(1, len(values)):
        value = values[i]
        if value > max_value:
            max_value = value
            max_arg = i
    return max_arg


@njit(cache=True)
def neighbor_argmax(a):
    height, width = a.shape[0] - 2, a.shape[1] - 2
    out = np.empty((height, width), dtype=np.uint8)
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            # window: a[y:y + 3, x:x + 3]
            # center: a[y + 1, x + 1]
            out[y, x] = argmax(
                a[y, x + 1],  # up
                a[y + 1, x],  # left
                a[y + 1, x + 2],  # right
                a[y + 2, x + 1],  # down
            )
    return out


@njit(cache=True, parallel=True)  # Add parallel=True.
def neighbor_argmax_mt(a):
    height, width = a.shape[0] - 2, a.shape[1] - 2
    out = np.empty((height, width), dtype=np.uint8)
    for y in prange(height):  # Change this to prange.
        for x in range(width):
            # window: a[y:y + 3, x:x + 3]
            # center: a[y + 1, x + 1]
            out[y, x] = argmax(
                a[y, x + 1],  # up
                a[y + 1, x],  # left
                a[y + 1, x + 2],  # right
                a[y + 2, x + 1],  # down
            )
    return out


@stencil
def kernel(window):
    # window: window[-1:2, -1:2]
    # center: window[0, 0]
    return np.uint8(  # Don't forget to cast to np.uint8.
        argmax(
            window[-1, 0],  # up
            window[0, -1],  # left
            window[0, 1],  # right
            window[1, 0],  # down
        )
    )


@njit(cache=True)
def neighbor_argmax_stencil(a):
    return kernel(a)[1:-1, 1:-1]  # Slicing is not mandatory.


@njit(cache=True)
def neighbor_argmax_stencil_with_copy(a):
    return kernel(a)[1:-1, 1:-1].copy()  # Slicing is not mandatory.


@njit(cache=True, parallel=True)
def neighbor_argmax_stencil_mt(a):
    return kernel(a)[1:-1, 1:-1]  # Slicing is not mandatory.


@njit(cache=True)
def neighbor_argmax_stencil_inlined(a):
    f = stencil(lambda w: np.uint8(argmax(w[-1, 0], w[0, -1], w[0, 1], w[1, 0])))
    return f(a)[1:-1, 1:-1]  # Slicing is not mandatory.


def benchmark():
    size = 2000  # Total nbytes (in MB) for a.
    n = math.ceil(math.sqrt(size * (10 ** 6) / 4))
    rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
    a = rng.random(size=(n, n), dtype=np.float32)
    print(f"{a.shape=}, {a.nbytes=:,}")

    expected = baseline(a)
    # expected = neighbor_argmax_mt(a)
    assert expected.shape == (n - 2, n - 2) and expected.dtype == np.uint8

    candidates = [
        baseline,
        neighbor_argmax,
        neighbor_argmax_mt,
        neighbor_argmax_stencil,
        neighbor_argmax_stencil_mt,
        neighbor_argmax_stencil_with_copy,
        neighbor_argmax_stencil_inlined,
    ]
    name_len = max(len(f.__name__) for f in candidates)
    for f in candidates:
        assert np.array_equal(expected, f(a)), f.__name__
        t = timeit.repeat(lambda: f(a), repeat=3, number=1)
        print(f"{f.__name__:{name_len}} : {min(t)}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    benchmark()

Result:
a.shape=(22361, 22361), a.nbytes=2,000,057,284
baseline                          : 24.971996600041166
neighbor_argmax                   : 0.1917789001017809
neighbor_argmax_mt                : 0.11929619999136776
neighbor_argmax_stencil           : 0.2940085999434814
neighbor_argmax_stencil_mt        : 0.17756330000702292
neighbor_argmax_stencil_with_copy : 0.46573049994185567
neighbor_argmax_stencil_inlined   : 0.29338629997801036

I think these results are enough to make you consider giving Numba a try :)

The following section was added after this answer was accepted.
Here is the CUDA version. (I'm using numba 0.60.0)
from numba import cuda

@cuda.jit(device=True)
def argmax_cuda(values):  # cuda.jit cannot handle an arbitrary number of arguments.
    max_arg = 0
    max_value = values[0]
    for i in range(1, len(values)):
        value = values[i]
        if value > max_value:
            max_value = value
            max_arg = i
    return max_arg


@cuda.jit
def neighbor_argmax_cuda_impl(a, out):
    y, x = cuda.grid(2)
    if y < out.shape[0] and x < out.shape[1]:
        out[y, x] = argmax_cuda(
            # Make sure to use a tuple, not a list.
            (
                a[y, x + 1],  # up
                a[y + 1, x],  # left
                a[y + 1, x + 2],  # right
                a[y + 2, x + 1],  # down
            )
        )


def neighbor_argmax_cuda(a, out):
    # If the input/output array is not on the GPU, you can transfer it like this.
    # However, note that this operation alone takes longer than neighbor_argmax_mt.
    # a = cuda.to_device(a)
    # out = cuda.to_device(out)

    # Block settings. I'm not sure if this is the optimal one.
    threadsperblock = (16, 16)
    blockspergrid_x = int(np.ceil(out.shape[1] / threadsperblock[1]))
    blockspergrid_y = int(np.ceil(out.shape[0] / threadsperblock[0]))
    blockspergrid = (blockspergrid_x, blockspergrid_y)

    neighbor_argmax_cuda_impl[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](a, out)

    # Back to CPU, if necessary.
    # out = out.copy_to_host()
    return out

As Jérôme explained in detail, the time taken to transfer the input/output arrays from the host to the device cannot be ignored.
a.shape=(22361, 22361), a.nbytes=2,000,057,284
neighbor_argmax                         : 0.47917880106251687
neighbor_argmax_mt                      : 0.08353979291860014
neighbor_argmax_cuda (with transfer)    : 0.5072600540006533
neighbor_argmax_cuda (without transfer) : 9.134004358202219e-05

(I had to use another machine to use CUDA. For that reason, the results for the CPU are different from the ones I put above.)

neighbor_argmax has great performances on my machine. It turns out to be competitive with an optimized native SIMD code. Although I expected good performance, I did not expect Numba to generate a SIMD-friendly assembly code due to the condition.

Thanks for this! I actually had my entire implementation on Numba before migrating to CuPy and ditching Numba, even though they are allegedly interoperable. The problem is I've been having a lot of trouble getting them to work together, especially since the target="cuda" and target_backend="cuda" options have been removed from numba.jit and numba.njit. Do you know if your solution is CUDA-friendly?

@DanDan面 The mainstream solution is to write a Numba CUDA kernel (which only works on Nvidia GPUs). Note Numba introduces overheads (eg. Numpy access) compared to raw CUDA kernel despite being simpler to use. It can sometimes make a GPU code not much faster because of that. In this case, the kernel is relatively simple.

@DanDan面 I've also added a CUDA version (although I probably shouldn't have done that, but I was curious). My code is not CUDA compatible, but the solution is CUDA friendly. However, as JérômeRichard explained, given the transfer between host and device and the sliding window feature of cupy, etc, I recommend posting a new separate question to get the most accurate answer.

@ken Your CUDA implementation worked beautifully for me, and is also perfect for my use case. This is one part of a larger simulation that happens entirely on GPU. Thanks!


calling reshape here creates a (L-2) x (L-2) x 9 copy instead of a view

This is because the two last axis of the target array cannot be reshaped together here in Numpy. Indeed, it would mean the stride of the last dimension would be variable between items which is not supported (and will certainly never be because it would make many operations very slow and far more complicated). Strides can only be constant for a given axis. When a view cannot be created, Numpy performs an expensive copy.

Is there a way to do this operation in a vectorized fashion, but with a smaller memory footprint?

The key in such a case is to perform the operation chunk by chunk. If the input is big, it can be faster than computing the final array in one unique operation because of CPU cache and page faults. Indeed, the temporary array can be recycled in memory. That being said, the chunks need not to be too small or otherwise the overhead of calling Numpy function and the one of the CPython loop will become expensive.
If L is pretty big, you can just iterate line by line. Otherwise, you need to compute chunks of lines. Here is an example:
swv = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(a, (3, 3)) # (L-2) x (L-2) x 3 x 3

out = np.empty((L-2, L-2), dtype=np.uint8)
k = 8
for i in range(0, L-2, k):
    out[i:i+k] = swv[i:i+k,:,:,:].reshape(-1, L-2, 9)[:,:,1::2].argmax(axis = 2).astype(np.uint8)


Benchmark
Here are performance results for a = np.random.rand(L, L).astype(np.float32) with L = 1000 on my machine with a i5-9600KF and Numpy 1.24.3:
Initial implementation:
    - time: 51 ms
    - memory overhead: O(L**2)

Proposed implementation:
    - time: 43 ms
    - memory overhead: O(L * k)

The computation is faster here for all k<30. For k>=30, the arrays are too big for the computation to be efficient and it takes roughly the same time than your computation (in fact, the proposed implementation is slightly faster even in this case). We can also conclude that CPython loops are not slow as long as the chunks are big enough for the overheads to be small compared to the computation time. The computation also takes less memory. The only downside is that the code is bigger. There is no free lunch.

Notes and faster implementations
Note that a reasonable value for k can be max(int(512*1024 / (3*3*a.itemsize*(L-2)) + 0.5), 1). With this formula, the computation should take no more than few MiB of RAM if possible. If this is not possible because k=1, then it should take C*a.itemsize*(L-2)*3*3/1024**2 MiB where C is a small constant (typically 2).
Here is an extended benchmark with other competitive implementations:
nocomment's first implementation ("mine"):
    - time: 19 ms
    - memory overhead: O(L**2)

nocomment's second implementation ("mine4"):
    - time: 13 ms
    - memory overhead: O(L**2)

Native scalar code:
    - time: 1.5 ms
    - memory overhead: O(1)

ken's best implementation ("neighbor_argmax"):
    - time: 0.38 ms
    - memory overhead: O(1)

Optimized native SIMD code:
    - time: 0.25 ms
    - memory overhead: O(1)

The nocomment's first implementation is faster but it requires significantly more memory (though less than the initial code). Indeed, at least 3 temporary boolean arrays needs to be allocated simultaneously. The size of each boolean array is (L-2)**2 bytes. This means at least 3 * (L-2)**2 bytes need to be allocated. This is significantly more than C * k * L (where C is a constant which should be 30~50) as long as k stay small and L is relatively big. The second implementation is faster on my machine, but it should also require more memory.
The ken's (best sequential) implementation is great since Numba generates an assembly code using SIMD instructions and its memory usage is very tiny (like native codes). It is not as good as an optimized native code but pretty close to. I think the main downside is the significant compilation time (800 ms only paid once during the very-first call).
On top of that, one can note that Numpy is far slower that what can be implemented in a native code (e.g. in C/C++). The gap is even bigger when he native code is optimized to benefit from SIMD units available on all mainstream CPUs. A native code requires <1KiB of additional memory. There is no chance for a Numpy code to be even close to that performance. An optimized SIMD-friendly native code is about 34 times faster than the proposed Numpy implementation and 200 times faster than the initial code while also using even less memory!
Overall, we can see that there is a huge gap between native/jitted codes and ones using only Numpy both in term of memory usage and speed.

Note about using GPUs
Regarding performance, a GPU code is not going to be faster (than the native and ken solutions) if the input array is stored in (host) RAM. Indeed, on my machine the two fastest CPU implementation are already close to be memory-bound while they only use a single CPU core! Once multithreaded, they are completely memory-bound. This should be true on all mainstream machine. There is no way to make a code faster than that since the input needs at least to be read from the RAM and the output needs at least to be written (and this is already a bottleneck for a fast multithreaded implementation). To perform the computation on a GPU, data must be moved from the host RAM to the device RAM (i.e. GPU RAM). This data transfer is generally done using the PCI interconnect which is always slower than the host RAM (often actually significantly slower). Some high-end servers benefits from a generally faster NvLink interconnect but the idea is the same: the interconnect is slower than the host memory. Thus, all GPU code will be slower than the fastest multithreaded CPU codes for this problem.
That being said, a GPU code can be faster than the fastest CPU code if the input and output arrays are stored on the GPU device (and not moved from/to the host one).
One way to write a GPU implementation is simply to use Cupy. To do that you need to first replace all np namespace with cp, then import cupy as cp, and then use cupy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided instead of the current sliding_window_view. This is simple, but also pretty inefficient. I expect the version of nocomment to be more GPU-friendly and still simple to port on GPU using the same method (i.e. using Cupy). That being said, it is still far from being efficient because it creates big temporary arrays in GPU RAM which are not needed. VRAM accesses are expensive. To get a fast code, you need to write a GPU kernel (eg. using OpenCL or CUDA -- the later only fully works on Nvidia GPUs). This is lower-level, cumbersome and it requires to understand a bit how GPUs works, but the resulting speed-up is generally pretty big, especially for compute-bound operations.
If done correctly, this computation should be memory-bound. This means the speed-up of the fastest GPU code compared to the fastest CPU code is approximately GPU_VRAM_bandwidth / CPU_RAM_bandwidth. On a mainstream PC with a CPU/GPU having a similar price and power consumption, I think you can expect a 4~8x speed up. For example, on my machine with a Nvidia 1660 Super and 2x3200MHz DDR4 DIMM, the speed up should be 8 (though my GPU was more expensive and also consume a bit more power in practice).
There is a catch though, there are some additional overhead which makes a GPU implementation not so great in this specific case:

the GPU runtime (e.g. CUDA) needs to be initialized (which takes about 300 ms on my machine)
allocating data on GPU and starting kernel tend to be expensive (e.g. about dozens of µs per allocation and per kernel) not to mention synchronizations
the amount of memory on GPU is often smaller than on CPU

Thus, for L=1000, the speed up should be actually not so good, even if data is stored on the GPU. This overhead can be mitigated if you run multiple iteration of the same kernel or other operations.
Here is a simple untested CUDA kernel:
__global__ void compute_simd_kernel(float* arr, int size, uint8_t* out)
{
    const int i = blockIdx.y + 1;
    const int j = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x + 1;

    if (i < size - 1 && j < size - 1)
    {
        const float upVal = arr[(i-1)*size+j];
        const float leftVal = arr[i*size+j-1];
        const float rightVal = arr[i*size+j+1];
        const float downVal = arr[(i+1)*size+j];

        uint8_t maxPos = 0;
        float maxVal = upVal;

        if (leftVal > maxVal) {
            maxPos = 1;
            maxVal = leftVal;
        }
        if (rightVal > maxVal) {
            maxPos = 2;
            maxVal = rightVal;
        }
        if (downVal > maxVal) {
            maxPos = 3;
        }

        out[(i-1)*(size-2)+(j-1)] = maxPos;
    }
}


Thanks for teaching me about chunking and also profiling all the other proposed solutions in the comments! I went ahead and marked ken's answer as accepted as it is the fastest, but wanted to mention that your profiling of everything was very valuable.

Ok, I understand. I added a note about GPUs regarding the edit in your question. Note however it would be better to open a new question in such a case.

A few solutions that take much less memory than your original and are faster. Memory could be further reduced by chunking like Jérôme did. Measured wit L = 1000:
Memory:
59.76 bytes/element  original
 3.06 bytes/element  mine
 9.00 bytes/element  mine4
 8.96 bytes/element  mine5

Speed:
  9.8 ± 0.3 ms  mine
 11.0 ± 0.5 ms  mine5
 22.2 ± 1.7 ms  mine4
 99.1 ± 4.9 ms  original

Python: 3.12.2 (main, Jun 12 2024, 09:13:57) [GCC 14.1.1 20240522]
NumPy:  1.26.4

I get the values in the four directions (Up/Left/Right/Down). In mine I compare all six pairs, store the comparison results as 6-bit numbers, and then look up what direction each 6-bit value means. In mine4 and mine5 I keep track of maximums.
import numpy as np


def original(a):
  swv = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(a, (3, 3))
  return swv.reshape(L-2, L-2, 9)[:,:,1::2].argmax(axis = 2).astype(np.uint8)


def mine(a):
  L = a[1:-1, :-2]
  R = a[1:-1, 2:]
  U = a[:-2, 1:-1]
  D = a[2:, 1:-1]
  cmp = (U < L).view(np.uint8)
  for (x, y) in (U, R), (U, D), (L, R), (L, D), (R, D):
    cmp = (cmp << 1) | (x < y).view(np.uint8)
  table = np.array([
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3,
      0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3,
      1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 2, 3
  ], dtype=np.uint8)
  return table[cmp]

# How I got my magic table
# table = np.zeros(64)
# table[mine(a)] = original(a)
# print(repr(table.astype(np.uint8)))


def mine4(a):
  U = a[:-2, 1:-1]
  L = a[1:-1, :-2]
  R = a[1:-1, 2:]
  D = a[2:, 1:-1]

  max = np.maximum(U, L)
  dir = (L > U).view(np.uint8)

  dir[R > max] = 2
  max = np.maximum(max, R)

  dir[D > max] = 3

  return dir


def mine5(a):
  U = a[:-2, 1:-1]
  L = a[1:-1, :-2]
  R = a[1:-1, 2:]
  D = a[2:, 1:-1]

  return np.where(
    np.maximum(R, D) > np.maximum(U, L),
    (D > R).view(np.uint8) + 2,
    (L > U).view(np.uint8)
  )


funcs = [original, mine, mine4, mine5]

from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev
import sys
import random
import tracemalloc as tm

L = 1000
a = np.random.random((L, L)).astype(np.float32)

# Correctness
print('Correctness:')
expect = original(a)
for f in funcs:
  print((f(a) == expect).all(), f.__name__)

# Memory
print('\nMemory:')
for f in funcs * 2:
  tm.start()
  f(a)
  print(f'{tm.get_traced_memory()[1] / L**2 :5.2f} bytes/element ', f.__name__)
  tm.stop()

# Speed
times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):5.1f} ± {stdev(ts):3.1f} ms '
for _ in range(25):
    random.shuffle(funcs)
    for f in funcs:
        t = timeit(lambda: f(a), number=1) / 1
        times[f].append(t)
for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)

print('\nPython:', sys.version)
print('NumPy: ', np.__version__)

Attempt This Online!

Good try! However, It should take more memory than my code since this code operate on the whole array even though boolean arrays take only 1 byte/item. See my updated answer for a detailed analysis ;) . Moreover, the code is quite difficult to understand IMHO. Note I added native code performance in benchmarks just to see how slow are Numpy codes.

@JérômeRichard Why "try"? Did I not succeed? You said yourself that it takes less memory than theirs. Yes, of course it takes more than yours. But the goal is to take less than theirs. I think with a few bytes per element, I take much less than their at least 9*4 bytes per element (if I understand correctly), so it might be small enough. And for further reductions, I mentioned chunking. Btw they said they have float32, so please measure with that. Using float64 seems to make my speed advantage smaller.

"Did I not succeed?" You did succeed to improve the OP solution, sure. I am not a native speaker so I may not use the best suited words (I see answers as proposal, hence why I use "try"). I also see my answer as a "try" (especially as long as it is not accepted or there is no feedback of the OP). I agree with you that this answer significantly improve the memory usage compared to the initial implementation.

Good point for the 32-bit floats. I updated the benchmark/answer. Interestingly, most solutions are left unaffected by this change. Only the native SIMD solution is. I think this is because all codes are compute-bound scalar ones and the speed of scalar operations is not affected by the type. I think the timings are a bit better because the array is twice smaller and so it should better fit in cache and reduce the pressure on RAM as well as page faults (which are not a bottleneck but impact performance).

By the way, I think your implementation might be a bit faster with .view(np.uint8) instead of .astype(np.uint8). The later creates a new array as opposed to the former. Besides this, I do not think there is a (much) better fully-vectorized implementation using only Numpy.

@JérômeRichard Ah, ok. Together with your "However, It should take more memory than my code" it sounded like I had tried/claimed that mine takes less memory than yours (though I'm no native speaker, either). Thanks for view, it does seem a bit faster (though hard to tell with my simple measuring on that machine). I wonder about the speed differences between our machines, why I measured mine to be more than 10 times faster than the original while you measured it to be less than 3 times faster...

Ok, I understand now. Sorry for the confusion. This is strange indeed. It is certainly be because of the Numpy version or your CPU (e.g. pretty recent CPU). What version do you use and which exact CPU?

@JérômeRichard NumPy 1.26.4 and some Skylake Xeon family 6 model 85 (says lscpu when I put that in "Advanced" there). I just added another solution, it's less fast for me, could you try it, too?

I tried to install Numpy 2.0 and CPython 3.12 and I got approximately the same behaviour (though the performance of your function was slightly better like ~16 ms for mine and ~12 ms for mine4). I also have a Skylake-like CPU so this is not the CPU architecture. The only difference I see is possibly bigger/different L3 cache and a different RAM (throughput & latency). Note I used Windows for this bench.

@JérômeRichard Thanks. Another interesting speed difference.
